# Python: properly construct, write and read MultiIndex pd to csv

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I would like to generate a pandas dataframe with several columns, each of them having more and different sub-columns.
Then I want to write it to a csv and read from it, maintaining the indexing right.

Here's an exemple:

```
col_1 = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([ ('Numbers', 'one'), ('Numbers','two')] )
col_2 = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([ ('Letters', 'A'), ('Letters', 'B'), ('Letters', 'C') ] )
num_data = [[0,1],[2,3]]
num_df = pd.DataFrame(num_data, columns=col_1)
let_data = [['a','b','c'],['d','e','f']]
let_df = pd.DataFrame(let_data, columns=col_2)
tot_df = pd.concat([let_df,num_df], axis=1)
```

Which gives:

```
  Letters       Numbers    
        A  B  C     one two
0       a  b  c       0   1
1       d  e  f       2   3
```

Q1: Is there a better way to do this? How can I define the whole table without a concat?
Q2: How do I extract the values from one row?
When I try to extract one line, I get into troubles, specifically when I type

```
tot_df.loc[tot_df['Letters','A'] == ['a'] ]
```

and this is because "tot_df['Letters','A'].values" returns an array = ['a' 'd'] rather than (what I would expect) a list ['a', 'd'].

Q3: Moving now to the printing/reading part, I usually use the to_csv() and read_csv() methods, but I get an unfolded 1D header as in the following:

```
tot_df.to_csv('multi_col.csv')
read_df = pd.read_csv('multi_col.csv', index_col = 0 )
read_df

     Letters Letters.1 Letters.2 Numbers Numbers.1
NaN        A         B         C     one       two
 0.0       a         b         c       0         1
 1.0       d         e         f       2         3
```

Could anyone of you suggest a better solution?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q1: You can join list of tuples together and also data in list by list comprehension and call only once `DataFrame` constructor:

```
col_1 = [('Numbers', 'one'), ('Numbers','two')]
col_2 = [('Letters', 'A'), ('Letters', 'B'), ('Letters', 'C')]
num_data = [[0,1],[2,3]]
let_data = [['a','b','c'],['d','e','f']]

tot_df = pd.DataFrame([a + b for a, b in zip(num_data, let_data)], 
                      columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(col_1 + col_2))
print (tot_df)
  Numbers     Letters      
      one two       A  B  C
0       0   1       a  b  c
1       2   3       d  e  f
```

Q2: For filter by `MultiIndex` use `tuples`, for complicated select use [slicers](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#using-slicers):

```
print (tot_df.loc[tot_df[('Letters','A')] == 'a'])
  Numbers     Letters      
      one two       A  B  C
0       0   1       a  b  c
```

Q3: For writing to file add parameter `index=False` for remove default index and for reading add parameter `header` with list of positions of `Multiindex` - first 2 rows of file:

```
tot_df.to_csv('multi_col.csv', index=False)
read_df = pd.read_csv('multi_col.csv', header= [0,1])
print (read_df)
  Numbers     Letters      
      one two       A  B  C
0       0   1       a  b  c
1       2   3       d  e  f
```